# Spring-Security: use of a custom authenticator AND a custom loginpage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to do first steps with Spring Boot Security.

I try to combine a custom Authenticator with a custom loginpage and I am not sure how to combine them.
Both of them alone work well.

**My custom authenticator (Auth)**

```
@Component
public class Auth implements AuthenticationProvider 
{
  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate (Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
  {

    String name = authentication.getName ();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString ();

    System.out.println ("auth: " + name + " / " + password);

    // no checks for now - any input is ok     
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (name, password, new ArrayList <GrantedAuthority> ());  
  }        

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }
}
```

**My security config (WebSecurity)**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{
  @Override
  protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
  {
    http.authorizeRequests ()
      .anyRequest ().authenticated ()
      .and ()
      .formLogin ()
       // .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
      .permitAll ();
    }

    @Autowired
    private Auth authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
      // register my custom authenticator here
      auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```

**My handler for /login (login)**

```
@RequestMapping ("/login")
public String login (HttpServletRequest request, Model model) 
{
  System.out.println("login")
  return "login";
}
```

If I am not using the custom-loginpage (.loginPage etc. in comments) my custom authenticator is in use and the builtin login-page does appear.

If I am using the custom-loginpage then my custom login.jsp is used but I see no usage of my custom authenticator. But the handler for /login is called.

So should the combination of a custom authenticator and a custon loginpage work out of the box OR
do I need to glue them together (in the login-handler maybe)??

**EDIT**

login.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        MyLogin
        <form action="/security_check" method="post">               
            username<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>        
            <br/>
            password<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>    
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="login"/>
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

My new security config:

```
http.authorizeRequests ()
    .antMatchers ("/sec*").permitAll ()
    .anyRequest ().authenticated ()
    .and ()
    .formLogin ().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/security_check")
    .permitAll ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it is only working if I have a hidden information in the login-page.

```
<input type="hidden"
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Then I do not need

```
formLogin ().loginPage("/login")
```

in the config - nothing more.

Not sure why but I take it.

I have it from:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-security/custom-login-page.html

Answer (score 1):

your configuration of custom authenticator is correct. The issue is with your custom login page.

so your custom login page should include at least a form with two fields: username and password, and also a POST action to a url, say "/security_check", which spring security will process the username and password. And in your spring security configuration, you will configure it to loginProcessingUrl like this:

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/security_check").permitAll();
```

of course, you can also specify the username parameter, password parameter like what you are doing now.

```
usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
```

the part you are missing was the loginProcessingUrl to hook your custom login page with spring security, which will use your custom authenticator to authenticate the user.

Comment: Do I need to implement the handler for security_check by myself? Needs the form action point to security_check?

Comment: Nope, you don’t have to

Comment: I addes my login.jsp and the changes security-config. The custom authenticator is still not called :-(

Comment: Then the loginpage is not found. I have spring-boot config for jsp in place. 

My loginpage is found, but the custom authenticator is not called. The request to /security_check is sent after my browser-logs.

Comment: Hmm, can you remove: antMatchers ("/sec*").permitAll () from the configuration?

Comment: Already tried - no call of the authenticator. Do I need an manual implementation for security_check or at least a registered ViewController?